# need to extract information in html elements using python an print it

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am looking to extract information within the div tag or class element in html and print the output in python.

I want to print the "**xyz**" in the html code.

```
<div data="xyz" data-index="3" class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28" data-cel-widget="search_result_3"><div class="sg-col-inner">
```

Python Code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

data_class = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28"})

for data1 in data_class:

    print(data1.get('data'))
```

Comment: and what is happening with your current code? Is there a problem?

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Answer (score 0):

Your "class" attribute consists of multiple classes. If you need to filter by multiple classes bs4 expects them in a list, not a single string with the classes seperated by a space.
Do something like `data_class = soup.find_all("div", {"class": ["sg-col-20-of-24", "s-result-item"]})` only with all the classes of course, not just the ones  just added as an example